# 3 Server Kafka Cluster write to 3 instances of Logstash

Tags: apache-kafka, logstash

I currently have a kafka cluster of 3 servers with this set up:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper server1.com:2181, 
server2.com:2181,server3.com:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partitions 1 --topic kafkatest3
```

I posted this command in cmd line on server1 and got confirmation that the topic is running.
I have one instance of logstash running on each server with this config

```
input {
            kafka
            {
                    bootstrap_servers => "server1.com:2181,server2.com:2181,server3.com:2181"
                    topics => "kafkatest3"
                    consumer_threads => 3
                    #group_id => "logstash"
            }
    }
    output
    {
            syslog
            {
                    host => ["syslogserver.com"]
                    port => 514
            }
    }
```

What I keep seeing consistently with this config is that only one instance of logstash appears to be writting to syslog. The other two sit there idly.

Is there a way to force each logstash into action? Is my # of partitions/# of consumer threads correct?

Thanks,
Karan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kafka only allows one consumer at a time to read from any given partition. You created your topic with only one partition, so the maximum number of consumer that will be able to read from that topic (for a consumer group) is one - which is what you are seeing.

If you kill the Logstash that is writing data you should see one of the other two picking up and processing data.

To get all three to get a fair share of the data you need to change your topic to have at least three partitions.

Comment: So if I were to have 3 partitions, would I need to have 3 consumer threads on each logstash instance or just 1 each? Also do I need to declare group 'logstash' to avoid duplicates on output side? Thanks.

Comment: I don't know what Logstash does internally, but I assume it uses a Consumer object per Logstash and then shares that across worker threads. If that assumption is correct you can have as many worker threads as you want. But the overall number of consumers that 3 partitions can support for the same consumer group is 3 after that consumers will idle.
The group defaults to logstash, which is why this should work out of the box, but I'd recommend setting this to an explicit value that tells you something to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Load balancing is working really well. Thanks.